# Digital Ocean : Mariadb connection refused

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, mariadb, digital-ocean

When I run my spring boot project through IDE works fine and perfect,

But when I try to deploy it on Digital Ocean's droplet it throws an Exception :

```
SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=127.0.0.1)(port=3308)(type=primary). Connection refused
```

And i'am pretty sure about the credential ; It already went fine on my IDE .

Comment: Are you sure port is 3308 and not 3306 ?

Comment: @GeorgRichter Yes very sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a credential issue, "Connection refused" is the java standard message when a socket fails to establish, so the problem is before authentication.

The problem is either nothing is listening on the IP:Port you are trying to connect to or the port is blocked by a firewall.

check that loopback 127.0.0.1 is defined with command like :

```
ip addr show lo
```

run

```
sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :3308
```

to ensure that something is listening on port.
expected answer are like :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3308            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      76468/mariadbd      
tcp6       0      0 :::3308                 :::*                    LISTEN      76468/mariadbd
```

Comment: Answer for the first command :  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: And the second command returned nothing

Comment: if second command return nothing, then server is not up, or listening on other port